# dynamically Re-arrange order of div using javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck in a problem where I have to re-arrange div's inside a div.

This html is in ajax response. There are accordions inside div with IDs like accordion 0 accordion 1 ,.... accordion 4.

How can I re-arrange these divs using javascript?

```js
function GetHtmlUsingAjax() {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((result) => { // result here contains the html given above
      //how can i re-arrange their order using javascript as div0,1,2,3..
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="sudiv0">
    <div id="accordion0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sudiv2">
    <div id="accordion2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sudiv1">
    <div id="accordion1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sudiv3">
    <div id="accordion3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @connexo , I know accordion is not a tag ,but can we re-arrange div taking something else inside instead of accordion

Comment: let me edit this html a little.

Comment: Your snippet still has the script tags in it in the JS section. If you remove them your JS error goes away. Please show us the code of anything you have tried already.

Comment: hi @connexo , I have edited html .

Comment: hi @AHaworth , this code is just for getting an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

PS DIVs do not have values

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container"); // or use a fragment
// container.innerHTML = response.text();
// demo string, remove when using the response
container.innerHTML = `<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="sudiv0">
    <div id="accordion0">accordion 0</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sudiv2">
    <div id="accordion2">accordion 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sudiv1">
    <div id="accordion1">accordion 1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sudiv3">
    <div id="accordion3">accordion 3</div>
  </div>
</div>`

const main = document.getElementById("maindiv");
[...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=sudiv]")]
  .sort((a,b) => a.id.replace("sudiv","") - b.id.replace("sudiv",""))
  .forEach(div => main.appendChild(div))
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: hi @mplungjan , here in this statement while creating an array [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=sudiv]")]  ,  I wanted to use the response html after fetching api. what should i use in place of "document" ?

Comment: Do I have to use this querySelector after inserting response html to page? Or before rendering to page?

Comment: I suggest you render  but you can use a fragment too. See update